# Spring-WebClient: What is the right way to handle the block method when an exception is presented?

Tags: java-11, spring-webclient

I have this code for this for overloaded methods:

```
public static <R, S> R executeRetrieveCall(WebClient webClient, HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                           URI uri, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, S bodyRequest, 
                                           Class<R> returnClass) {

    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = getResponseSpec(webClient, httpMethod, uri, httpHeaders, bodyRequest);
    Mono<R> mono = responseSpec.bodyToMono(returnClass);
    return getBlock(uri, bodyRequest, mono);
}

public static <R, S> R executeRetrieveCall(WebClient webClient, HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                           URI uri, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, S bodyRequest,
                                           ParameterizedTypeReference<R> returnClass) {

    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = getResponseSpec(webClient, httpMethod, uri, httpHeaders, bodyRequest);
    Mono<R> mono = responseSpec.bodyToMono(returnClass);
    return getBlock(uri, bodyRequest, mono);
}
```

The code for `getResponseSpec` method is:

```
private static <S> WebClient.ResponseSpec getResponseSpec(WebClient webClient, HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri,
                                                          HttpHeaders httpHeaders, S bodyRequest) {

    WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec = webClient.method(httpMethod);
    WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec = requestBodyUriSpec.uri(uri);

    if (httpHeaders != null) {
        requestBodySpec = requestBodySpec.headers(headers -> headers.putAll(httpHeaders));
    }
    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;
    if (bodyRequest != null) {
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> requestHeadersSpec = requestBodySpec.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(bodyRequest));
        responseSpec = requestHeadersSpec.retrieve();
    } else {
        responseSpec = requestBodySpec.retrieve();
    }
    return responseSpec;
}
```

And the code for `getBlock` method is:

```
private static <R, S> R getBlock(URI uri, S bodyRequest, Mono<R> mono) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String CALLER_ERROR = "errorMessage: %s, uri: %s, body: < %s >."

    return mono.doOnSuccess(response ->
                    log.info(gson.toJson(response))
            ).doOnError(error ->
                    log.error(String.format(CALLER_ERROR, error.getMessage(), uri, bodyRequest),
                    error)
            )
            .block();
}
```

When I have an Exception an example like this:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized from POST http://destiny-ms-util-develop-svc.bci-api:8080/operations/security/destiny-ms-util/develop/oauth/token
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:219)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 401 from POST http://destiny-ms-util-develop-svc.bci-api:8080/operations/security/destiny-ms-util/develop/oauth/token [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:207)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:413)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:424)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:478)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:712)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:102)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1712)
        at us.com.activity.client.destinyms.DestinyMsUtilClientImplTest.login(DestinyMsUtilClientImplTest.java:116)
        at us.com.activity.util.startup.RunAfterStartupUtil.runAfterStartup(RunAfterStartupUtil.java:25)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344)
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$running$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:358)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1359)
        at us.com.activity.ConsumerApplication.main(ConsumerApplication.java:52)
```

I see some thing (is like extra additional exception):

```
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:207)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:413)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:424)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:478)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:712)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I think like the main reason of the exceptions is the `supressed`...

and, maybe I'm doing something bad handling the `WebClientResponseException`

**What is the right way to handle the `block` method when an exception is presented?**